# Pass a String from External Class with Function in flutter to main file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class in Flutter which retrieve device IP Address:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as https;

class CheckIp {

  Future<String> getIP(String text) async {

    try {
      const url = 'https://api.ipify.org';
      var response = await https.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        return response.body;
      } else {
        print(response.body);
        return null;
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

and I call this class in the main file :

```
@override
  void initState() {
    CheckIp().getIP(ipAddress);
  
  }
```

now what I want to do is to get from the class the the string relative to `response.body`
and pass this string into the main file
any suggestion?

Comment: Means get value of the function and pass it to somewhere else?

Comment: the value of the function is response.body need to pass this data somewhere else as String

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would format the CheckIp class like this:

You are not actually using the `text` parameter, so why not deleting it?

The `getIP()` function can be static so you don't need to instantiate the `CheckIp` class.

Then, the method return a Future of type String, so you should return empty string instead of null to avoid errors.

```
class CheckIp {

  static Future<String> getIP() async {
    try {
      const url = 'https://api.ipify.org';
      var response = await https.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        return response.body;
      } else {
        print(response.body);
        return '';
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

Then, for the main:

```
late ipAddress;

  @override
  void initState() async {
    ipAddress = await CheckIp.getIP();
  }
```

Comment: This doesnt work... Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type '_Future<String>'

Comment: Where do you get the error? Are you using the 'await' in the main?

Comment: I am using exactly as you wrote.

Comment: Please, share the code line where you get the error if you need further help